# unable to save excel sheet via vb2010

Tags: vb.net

I am unable to save excel sheet through an application I have developed in vb 2010.It is able to create a file and is entering all the data assigned but gives a COM exception unhandled when it hits the save command:-
 xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\ABC", "xlsx")
 I have added references to excel in my visual studio 2010.

Below is the code i am using:-

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    'Add a New Workbook
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

    'Display Excel
    xlApp.Visible = False

    'Set the relebant sheet that we want to work with
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With xlWorkSheet
        'Directly type the values that we want
        .Range("A1").Value = "Company Name"
        .Range("A2").Value = "Product Name"
        .Range("A3").Value = "Budget"
        .Range("A4").Value = "Expected Delivery"

        .Range("B1").Value = "hi"
        .Range("B2").Value = "hh"
        .Range("B3").Value = "qw"
        .Range("B4").Value = "qw"
    End With

    'Save the file
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\ABC", "xlsx")

    'Close the file
    'xlWorkBook.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you running your application "As Administrator"?

Answer (score 2):

use :

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\ABC.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you code as :

```
''Add a New Workbook

    Dim AppExcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim Classeur As Excel.Workbook = AppExcel.Workbooks.Add()
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Classeur.ActiveSheet
    'Display Excel
    AppExcel.Visible = False

    'Set the relebant sheet that we want to work with

    With xlWorkSheet
        'Directly type the values that we want
        .Range("A1").Value = "Company Name"
        .Range("A2").Value = "Product Name"
        .Range("A3").Value = "Budget"
        .Range("A4").Value = "Expected Delivery"

        .Range("B1").Value = "hi"
        .Range("B2").Value = "hh"
        .Range("B3").Value = "qw"
        .Range("B4").Value = "qw"
    End With

    'Save the file

    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("C:\ABC3.xlsx"
```

Answer (score 0):

Both above answers seems correct, but lack explanations.

> expression .SaveAs(FileName, FileFormat, Password, WriteResPassword,
>   ReadOnlyRecommended, CreateBackup, AccessMode, ConflictResolution,
>   AddToMru, TextCodepage, TextVisualLayout, Local)

Above is excel `SaveAs` method all parameters being optional.

```
Filename
Optional
Variant
```

> A string that indicates the name of the file to be saved. You can
>   include a full path; if you don't, Microsoft Excel saves the file in
>   the current folder.

Important part in above is name, which you missed.

```
FileFormat
Optional
Variant
```

> The file format to use when you save the file. For a list of valid
>   choices, see the XlFileFormat enumeration. For an existing file, the
>   default format is the last file format specified; for a new file, the
>   default is the format of the version of Excel being used.

You got error because you specified path with no filename. 
changing this line

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\ABC", "xlsx")
```

to 
xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\ABC.xlsx")
fixes a problem.

[References to other info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
      xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
      xlApp.Visible = False
       xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With xlWorkSheet
        'Directly type the values that we want
        .Range("A1").Value = "Company Name"
        .Range("A2").Value = "Product Name"
        .Range("A3").Value = "Budget"
        .Range("A4").Value = "Expected Delivery"

        .Range("B1").Value = "hi"
        .Range("B2").Value = "hh"
        .Range("B3").Value = "qw"
        .Range("B4").Value = "qw"
    End With
      xlWorksheet.SaveAs("C:\ABC", "xlsx")
  End Sub
```

Comment: are you happy with this program then share it